# Could anyone explain to me syntax for longtable?

Tags: longtable, syntax

What does `\begin{longtable}{@{}l*{9}{c}@{}}` exactly mean?

Comment: The same as \begin{tabular}{@{}|*{9}{c}@{}}, only for a longtable.  @{} means "do not add a gap here", | means "add a vertical line here", *{9}{c} means "ccccccccc".

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I am new to latex and don't understand the syntax. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Most of these things are explained in the package manuals, except that tabular is standard LaTeX.  Some LaTeX editors provide online help for standard LaTeX.

Comment: https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-08

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is solved by comments.